# Audio Playback in an HTML5 Video Element using HLS

Tags: javascript, html, video, http-streaming, m3u8

I'm in the process of integrating an M3U8 video playlist using HTML5's video element, specifically for Safari and I've got it working. The only issue is that the audio for that video doesn't play or just doesn't exist. However, the flash version of this player does play the audio track associated with each video.

So my question is, if anyone knows, does HTML5 Video Element in Safari also play the audio of that video?

Any ideas, hints and/or tricks would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: depends on the video and its codecs, we don't know which one "that video" is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very simple

You should use it code

```
<video src="http://192.168.10.69:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wowzaaudioonly" controls autoplay >
</video>
```

in your case, enter your owns parameters

```
<video src="http://[IP-server]:[PORT]/[DIR]/playlist.m3u8 controls autoplay >
</video>
```

in wowza

```
<video src="http://[ip-server]:1935/vod/mp4:[filename].mp4/playlist.m3u8" controls autoplay >
</video>
```

Joel